# To assign and print the values from loop to different variables using python

Tags: python, loops, opencv, for-loop, mouseevent

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
boxes = []
d={}
global a
def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print 'Mouse Position: '+str(x)+', '+str(y)
        sbox = [x, y]
        boxes.append(sbox)
        for a in range(1,4):
            d["string{0}".format(a)]=x,y
img = cv2.imread('SAM15.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = 1,fy = 1)
cv2.namedWindow('real image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('real image', on_mouse, 0)
cv2.imshow('real image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My aim is to assign and print the three points which i will be consecutively clicking on the image. The problem i am facing is, i was only able to print the third(final) click points on image. I was stuck with the loop. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance !

The output should be like this
{'string1': (87, 26), 'string2': (84, 78), 'string3': (42, 62)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are looping through the values of `a` every time the mouse button is clicked. Instead, you need to test to see if there are three elements in `boxes` and only execute the for loop if there are.

Comment: How to test the boxes for three elements ?  I am not getting you @SSteve

Comment: now I am able to access. I have three elements in boxes. i am able to print individual after running. But, I try to print the elements like boxes[0] in the program itself. Its showing like- IndexError: list index out of range.@SSteve

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some basic debugging. Always check the length of an array before trying to access an element (or only access elements in a loop controlled by the array length). If your array is empty when you don't expect it to be, you need to trace through your code, adding debugging statements if necessary, to see where the array value is changing.